# How to read csv file, and add header and new columns based on data in csv and output new csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

After running a python script that compares two csv files, I am left with a new csv file that lists only email addresses for new students. (This will be used later to auto create new users in our email system).

However, I need to take the csv file that has only email addresses and based on the info in the email address, create a new csv file that has a header of firstname, lastname, email,  and then has the appropriate data for each line.

Example:

Original csv (newemails.csv)

```
john.doe@mydomain.com
terry.jackson@mydomain.com
silly.sally@mydomain.com
```

New CSV file should look like:

```
firstname, lastname, email
John, Doe, john.doe@mydomain.com
Terry, Jackson, terry.jackson@mydomain.com
Silly, Sally, silly.sally@mydomain.com
```

This is my current code, which gives me the newemails.csv file

```
import csv
import os
import subprocess

def newemails():

for line in fileinput.input(r'C:\gamwork\currentstudents.csv', inplace=1):
    print(line.lower(), end='')


with open(r'C:\gamwork\previoususers.csv', 'r') as t1, 
open(r'C:\gamwork\currentstudents.csv', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open(r'C:\gamwork\newemails.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
```

I am really not sure what to do from here and any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: What is your question? Are you just looking for pointers (off-topic) or do you have an issue?

Comment: FWIW I don't see any obvious blockers in your code knowledge to keep going on and then come back when you hit a brick wall

Comment: Rather than just `outFile.write(line)`, you should process the line and create a new string with the names, and then write that

Comment: You can write the headers before reading the lines in filetwo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:
if your file contains

```
john.doe@mydomain.com
terry.jackson@mydomain.com
silly.sally@mydomain.com
```

then you can do the following:

```
with open('mydata.csv', 'r') as f, open('out.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write('First name, last name, email\n')
    for line in f:
        names, email = line.split('@')[0], line
        first, last = names.split('.')
        new_line = f'{first}, {last}, {email}'
        out_file.write(new_line)


with open('out.csv', 'r') as out_file:
    print(out_file.read())
```

output:

```
First name, last name, email
john, doe, john.doe@mydomain.com
terry, jackson, terry.jackson@mydomain.com
silly, sally, silly.sally@mydomain.com
```

Comment: This works perfectly. and very simple and easy to follow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved using `pandas`
please find a sample below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test3.csv',  header=None, names=['Email'])
df['FirstName'] = [x.split('.')[0].title() for x in df['Email']]
df['LastName'] = [x.split('.')[1].split('@')[0].title() for x in df['Email']]
df = df.drop('Email', 1)
print(df)
df.to_csv('students.csv')
```

or another solution is

```
import pandas as pd

def createFirstLastNames(row):
    firstLast = row['Email'].split('@')[0]
    firstName = firstLast.split('.')[0].title()
    lastName = firstLast.split('.')[1].title()
    return pd.Series({
        'FirstName' : firstName,
        'LastName' : lastName
    })

df = pd.read_csv('test3.csv',  header=None, names=['Email'])
df1 = df.merge(df.apply(lambda row: createFirstLastNames(row), axis=1), left_index=True, right_index=True)
df1 = df1.drop('Email', 1)
print(df1)
df1.to_csv('students.csv')
```

the output is as follows

```
FirstName LastName
John      Doe
Terry  Jackson
Silly    Sally
```